# Prove $x_2$ is a sol of $x'=Ax$ given $x_1$ is a sol.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> Suppose $2 \times 1$ vector $x_1(t) = [u(t), v(t)]^T$ is a solution of $x' = Ax$ where $A$ is a $2 \times 2$ matrix of real numbers.
>
> Prove that $2 \times 1$ vector $x_2(t) = [ku(k^2t), kv(k^2t)]^T$ is also a solution of $x' = Ax$.

---

From #5a [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gxgoqpc3l80e70n/AADPqP2KRd7DvAXxW3RzQQT-a/MA%20161%20(Differential%20Equations)/MA%20161%20LT%202/Ma161LT2_2005_Tuprio.JPG?dl=0).

---

Apparently, solutions of $x' = Ax$ look like $x = e^{At}x(0)$ $(*)$

So given

$$\begin{bmatrix}
u(t)\\ 
v(t)
\end{bmatrix} = e^{At}\begin{bmatrix}
u(0)\\ 
v(0)
\end{bmatrix} \tag{**}$$

we must prove that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
ku(k^2t)\\ 
kv(k^2t)
\end{bmatrix} = e^{At}\begin{bmatrix}
ku(0)\\ 
kv(0)
\end{bmatrix}$$

---

What I tried:

$$RHS = e^{At}\begin{bmatrix}
ku(0)\\ 
kv(0)
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ = ke^{At}\begin{bmatrix}
u(0)\\ 
v(0)
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$= ke^{At}e^{-At}\begin{bmatrix}
u(t)\\ 
v(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$= k\begin{bmatrix}
u(t)\\ 
v(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$LHS = \begin{bmatrix}
ku(k^2t)\\ 
kv(k^2t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$= k \begin{bmatrix}
u(k^2t)\\ 
v(k^2t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$= k e^{A(k^2t)} \begin{bmatrix}
u(0)\\ 
v(0)
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$= k (e^{At})^{k^2} \begin{bmatrix}
u(0)\\ 
v(0)
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$= k (e^{At})^{k^2-1} e^{At}\begin{bmatrix}
u(0)\\ 
v(0)
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$= k (e^{At})^{k^2-1} \begin{bmatrix}
u(t)\\ 
v(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$= (e^{At})^{k^2-1} RHS$$

I'm stuck. Where did I go wrong? How can I approach this?

---

** Is there a way to prove this without using $(*)$?
**

It seems we are given that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
u'(t)\\ 
v'(t)
\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}
u(t)\\ 
v(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

and must prove that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
k^3u'(k^2t)\\ 
k^3v'(k^2t)
\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}
ku(k^2t)\\ 
kv(k^2t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

If I write $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} \ a_{12}\\ 
a_{21} \ a_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$ and multiply out the matrices, should I be able to prove the proposition? I tried that, but it doesn't look like I can prove it:

We are given that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
u'(t)\\ 
v'(t)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}u(t) + a_{12}v(t)\\
a_{21}u(t) + a_{22}v(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

and must prove that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
k^3u'(k^2t)\\ 
k^3v'(k^2t)
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}ku(k^2t) + a_{12}kv(k^2t)\\
a_{21}ku(k^2t) + a_{22}kv(k^2t)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Revise the statement, it does not seem to be true.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Thanks. Added link. Did I misinterpret?

Comment: "...for some $k$", not for every $k$. Er... well, for e.g. $k=1$ it is obvious, isn't it?

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Strange way of $\exists k$. Anyway, thanks ^-^ Post as answer? Edit: Oh wait $k=0,-1,1$?

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Wait, do you mean the question is equivalent to asking find some $k$ s.t. $(w,z)$ is a solution? So should I find the question weirdly stated? Why doesn't it just say that? In fact, it could even ask for the values of $k$ s.t. $(w,z)$ is a solution

Comment: Not only the question is weirdly stated, it is... well, uninteresting. The solutions are somewhat trivial and obvious, and the solution "procedure" is guessing, so I see no pedagogical point. I am speculating what the question really meant, but the first thing that came to my mind is an erratum.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia trivial and obvious because there is no ODE $\cap$ calculus$^C$ involved, and this is something a linear algebra student can answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is "for some" not "for all" k.

For the first proof, we can pick $k=0,1,-1$ since they satisfy $k(e^{At})^{k^2 - 1} = kI$.

For the second proof, we can pick $k=0,1,-1$ since they satisfy $k^3 = k$.